# how to detect if two words have been typed in an inputbox with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to figure out how to detect if two words have been typed in an inputbox with jquery or javascript. 
I am not sure how to do this, I can do a character limit but cant quite figure out if two words have been typed.

This is just a question, I do not have any code to display as I do not know where to begin

Comment: You can use a `blur` event in JavaScript on both the `input` boxes. On `blur` - check the values.

Comment: I would suggest the `keyup` event

Comment: Implement an event listener for the onkeyup event - it will fire every time a key has been pressed. Then check the whitespace in the string, or use split().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not counting spaces ?

```
function howManyWordsInInput(id)
{
    var text = document.getElementById(id).value;

    text = text.split(" ");

    return text.length;
}
```

Usage for 2 words : `if (howManyWordsInInput("YourInputID") == 2) {...}`

**EDIT**

For those who prefer single lined way :

```
if (document.getElementById("YourInputID").value.split(" ").length == 2) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   if$('input').val().split(/\s/).length===2){
// 2 words have been typed
 }
```

And bind this to the `keyup` event.

There are other ways too.  Many

- note that this dosent account for the user typing non word characters or numbers.

Comment: Meh, 10s before my post =p Anyway, jQuery is kind of simpler for this :)

Comment: He did say jQuery... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just use split to see how many words You have: http://fiddle.jshell.net/m4y9tscx/